# webpage: how to automate detection if webpage returns error?

Tags: html, jsp, servlets, glassfish

I have a webpage generated by an application server (GlassFish) using JSP pages. If the application server goes down, the webpage returns an error (can't find file).

Is there any way to set things up so I get an email when someone visits this page and observes an error? For example, using .htaccess or anything else (simple)?

Alternatively, is there a way I can automate pinging the webpage somehow every 30 minutes and send me an email if the webpage returns an error?

Or, anyway to automate querying the application server and notifying me when it goes down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the specific error?  I would imagine it's a 404 Can't Find File, unless the application itself is throwing the error.

If it's 404 then in your htaccess file add:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.domain.com/404page.html
```

Create a document called 404page.html and add it to your root directory via FTP.  Put something meaningful to the user so they know there is an error.  To inform you for the error you could create an auto submit form:

[Auto submit form](http://www.riyazwalikar.com/2013/11/auto-submit-onload-html-form-with-input.html)

Then you would need a simple php mailing script to grab the posted variables and mail send them via e-mail.

If it's not 404 you need to figure out where that error is being thrown from and add in an error page. But if the apps server is going down, I highly doubt it's responsible for throwing the error.

Comment: Yes, it's a 404 error for "Page not found". I already have a custom page setup for a generic 404 error. But, I only want to trigger the auto submit form on one specific webpage and not the entire website (e.g. the one webpage that is produced from JSP file, which requires the app server, and not those webpages generated by static HTML code). Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Are you comfortable with php? Essentially I would grab the URL using $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] then explode the url and analyze the portion that makes it unique to that page. Then have a simple conditional if statement IF == JSP file put your auto submit form, else put your normal 404 page code. Save it as 404page.php and change your htaccess file to reflect the new file. I would whip it up for you but won't by by a computer for a while.